# X.509 based authentication using a Web Browser

Tags: web-services, authentication, x509

I have a little Web App that consumes a Web Service using Basic Authentication. So far, so good.

What I'd like to do next is use X.509 Certificates for authentication instead of Basic Authentication. Is there a standard for this? I haven't found one so far ...

Answer (score 0):

SSL Client Authentication allows for this.  Implementation almost always depends on where your SSL connection terminates - so if in Apache, configure it there; if in Tomcat, there; etc..

Apache: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/ssl/ssl_howto.html#accesscontrol
Tomcat 7: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html